# Jquery Prettyphoto/colorbox/fancybox/stickytooltip all lightbox of iframe need to open in main page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, iframe

I need to open prettyphoto lightbox on iframe photos and now if i implement below code in iframe then it shown within iframe scope. i need to open lightbox in main page instead of iframe.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ load(); 
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();   
 });

<a href="<%=displayImageUrl%>" id="mainImgA" target="_blank" rel="prettyPhoto">
<img src="<%=displayImageUrl%>"  id="mainimg" width="235" height="180" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean a new window, not iframe. To prevent opening in a new window, remove { target="_blank" } from your code.